# Check if any parameters are given in a request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, parameters

I'm designing an API in Rails. If the developer supplies the parameters set by me through GET request it's OK. But what if he supplies a parameter not given by me??
For example let's say I accept parameter name in the URL. I can check that by

```
params[:name]
```

in my code right. What if the developer supplies the parameter names in his URL? How do I notify him that he can't do that?

In short my question comes to "How can I check if any other parameters are supplied in the URL" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply `params` contains all the parameters.

Try `debug(params)` in any view, just as an example; put in the URL any parameter, invented. You will see it in the `params` array.

So, you could do something like (pseudo-code):

```
valid_params = ["param1", "param2"]

params.each do |param|
  new_api_error unless valid_params.include? param
end
```

Comment: So, what should be the logic in my controller to filter those?

Comment: @user1616238 I have edited the answer; "new_api_error" its fictional, just a call to a method you will define to process the generated errors, but I think you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks dude... will definitely try that